# How to make a Floating Nav bar?

Tags: javascript, css, web

I got this site at http://www.f7tek.tk. The site has a white menu bar.

[image]

What i want is, when i scroll down the page this bar sticks on the top:

[image: Like so: i.stack.imgur.com/LKPnY.png]

I tried setting the *position* to **fixed** and setting the *z-index* to **1000**. That does almost everything I want but When I scroll down the bar stays at that position, doesn't move to the top like i wanted.

Is it possible using **CSS** only? what about **JavaScript**? If it is, then how?

Comment: You can use jquery for this. So when the top of the screen crosses a certain point the bar sticks to the top of the window. Look at this: http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: Use the on scroll event to check if the document is scrolled further then where the navbar is, then set the position to fixed.

Comment: @keesSonnema: how do i do it? can you explain the details. the website you mentioned is doing exactly what i wanted with their site

Comment: I will provide a simple example, just 1 second.

Comment: ^ It's already beyond a second, there's still no example. :l
Sorry just kidding.

Comment: here's your 1 second example :p http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/293/

Comment: @KeesSonnema thaks man. really helpful

Comment: Will paste it as an answer if it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema yes. that's what I am looking for

Comment: How come people gave so many -1s :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is to add a class to your header bar if you scroll to a certain point.

So if you have a header called `<div class="sticky-header">Your header</div>` and add a second class called `fixed` that will be applied after scrolling to 100px from the top of the window it will stick from there.

JQUERY:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
       $('.sticky-header').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
       $('.sticky-header').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top:0; left:0;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gxRC9/293/)

Comment: and someone edited the post so that it makes more sense. thanks everyone